# prove the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: $\int^b_af(x)\cos(nx)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for any regulated function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to prove the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, namely that $\int^b_af(x)\cos(nx)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for any regulated function $f$.

The textbook which I'm working from says that I need to prove 3 things in the following order:

1. For all $a \lt b$, show that $\int^b_a\cos(nx)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
2. By considering separately each interval of the partition, show that $\int^b_a\phi(x)\cos(nx)dx\rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $\phi(x)$  is a step function on $[a,b]$
3. Extend this to all $f \in R[a,b]$

So, here's my proof:

1. $\int^b_a\cos(nx)dx= \frac{1}{n}\sin(nb)-\frac{1}{n}\sin(na) \rightarrow 0$ by the sandwhich rule:
   $$-1 \leq \sin(nx) \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq \frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \leq 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)=0$$
   $\Rightarrow \int^b_a \cos(nx)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
2. Let $\phi(x) \in S[a,b]$ be a step function in $[a,b]$ and let $P=\{p_0,\ldots,p_k\}$  be a compatible partition with $\phi(x)$. Then:
   $$\int\phi(x)\cos(nx)dx= \frac{1}{n}\phi(x)\Bigl(\sin(nb)-\sin(na)\Bigr)+ \frac{1}{n^2}cos(nx)(p_i-p_{i-1}) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $x\in [p_i,p_i-1)$}$$
   using IBP: $\phi(x)=u \Rightarrow (p_i-p_{i-1})dx=du$ and then $\cos(nx)dx=dv \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)=v$. Hence, If I apply the same to every interval, $\int^b_a\phi(x)\cos(nx)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for each interval of the partition $P$.
3. Let $\phi_n \in S[a,b]$ be a sequence of step functions converging uniformly to $f$. Then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^b_a \phi_n \cos(nx)dx= \int^b_af(x)\cos(nx) \rightarrow 0$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ by (2)

Is my proof correct? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Part 1,2 are easy and you have correct approach there. For part 3 you need to use the following theorem : for every Riemann integrable function $f$ there is a sequence of step functions $s_n$ such that $\int_{a} ^{b} s_n(x) \, dx\to\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is *the* correct proof of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma (in the form you gave).

Let $I_n = \int_a^b f(x)\cos(nx)dx$. Changing $x$ to $x+\frac{\pi}{n}$ gives $I_n = \int_{a-\pi/n}^{b-\pi/n} f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})\cos(nx+\pi)dx$. Noting $\cos(nx+\pi) = -\cos(nx)$, we see $$2I_n = \int_{a-\pi/n}^a -f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})dx+\int_a^{b-\pi/n} [f(x)-f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})]\cos(nx)dx+\int_{b-\pi/n}^b f(x)\cos(nx)dx.$$ Say $|f(x)| \le C$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Then $$\left|\int_{a-\pi/n}^a -f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})dx\right| \le C\frac{\pi}{n}$$ $$\left|\int_{b-\pi/n}^b f(x)\cos(nx)dx\right| \le C\frac{\pi}{n}.$$ Also, by uniform continuity, for all $\epsilon > 0$, for $n$ large enough, $|f(x)-f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})| \le \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b-\frac{\pi}{n}]$, and so $$\left| \int_a^{b-\pi/n}  [f(x)-f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})]\cos(nx)dx\right| \le \epsilon(b-a).$$ Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |I_n| \le \frac{b-a}{2}\epsilon.$$ It follows that $I_n \to 0$, as desired.

Comment: why exactly does $I_n \to 0$ in the end?

Comment: @Marina $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |I_n| \le \frac{b-a}{2}\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ (and $\frac{b-a}{2}$ is just some fixed constant).

Comment: $f $ is not supposed to be continuous. Rather one has to prove this for Riemann integrable $f$.

Comment: The comment was deleted after the comment it referred to was self-deleted. It was then "no longer needed". If you want to keep the information around it is safer to include it in the post via an edit. Here is the relevant bit " The proof works for integrable f; the justifications are just a bit different. "

Comment: @quid it's definitely not the case that it was no longer needed. It provided a response to Paramanand's comment. When I post relevant comments, I don't think about keeping them safe...

Comment: @quid oh wait, do comments get deleted automatically (and not by moderators) if they @ someone who deleted a comment??

Comment: It is not automatically in a strict sense but if we get a "no longer needed" flag on a short comment that is a reply to a deleted comment we tend to delete quickly  without considering carefully whether the comment may be useful as reply to an entirely different comment. (We deleted a comment to a user named Thomas Shelby that was nowhere to be seen  in this thread anymore; the comment to Paramanand was self-deleted by you.) Maybe we should, yet, life is short and there are many flags. As said, if you want to high-light  "The proof works for integrable f" include it in  the post.

Comment: @quid yea, no problem, I understand wanting to save time. thanks!

Comment: @mathworker21 - Does this proof work for $f \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Bbb{R})$? *i.e.*, does this proof also show that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)cos(nx)dx \to 0 \  \text{as} \ n \to \infty$ since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary?

Comment: @TaylorRendon yes, by dominated convergence theorem