# Equation that seems to be true. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a f(t, \sin{nt})\,\mathrm dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a f(t, \cos{nt})\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I don't know why, but this equation seems to be true for several functions that I've tested. "a" is a real value and "f" is some function.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a f(t, \sin{nt})\,\mathrm dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a f(t, \cos{nt})\,\mathrm dx$$

ex.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2{nt}}{1+t} \,\mathrm dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2{nt}}{1+t}\,\mathrm dt = \frac{1}{2}\log(1+\frac{\pi}{2})$$

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04L5Q.png)
Here is a graph that graphs the equation above.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/20m87pszz8

My intuition tells me that each pair of neighboring hills made by sin and cos will eventually be indistinguishable and therefore the area will be the same.
However, I don't know a way to prove this.

Does anyone know a proof or a theorem relating to this problem?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral, at least the one in your posting,  is of the form
$$\int_I f(t)g(nt)\,dt$$
where  $g$ is bounded and $T$-periodic ($g(x+T)=g(x)$ for all $x$), $I$ is an interval (finite or not), and $f$ is a *nice* function.
The interpretation is that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the periodic function $averages out$.

- A [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) by [Féjer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip%C3%B3t_Fej%C3%A9r),  states that
  under if $f$ is integrable over $I$, then
  $$\lim_m\int_I f(t)g(nt)dt\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0g(t)\,dt \cdot \int_I f(t)\,dt$$
  Notice that $\sin^2(t)$ and $\cos^2(t)$ are both $\pi$ periodic and $\int^\pi_0\sin^2t\,dt=\int^\pi_0\cos^2t\,dt$

There a several postings on MSE about this with  different levels of difficulty. Here are a few ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068640/121671), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674499/121671), [3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1554225p9469156), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606500/121671)).

- On can also use the identities $\sin^2t=\frac{1-\cos 2t}{2}$ and $\cos^2t=\frac{1+\cos2t}{2}$ an use a well known result: [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), which states that for any *nice* function $f$
  $$\lim_n\int_I f(t)\sin nt\,dt=0=\lim_n\int_I f(t)\cos nt\,dt$$
  The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma can be obtained from the result of Féjer,