# The limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos{(\frac{n^2}{\cos^2 x})} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to evaluate the limit : $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos{(\frac{n^2}{\cos^2 x})} \mathrm{d} x$

It seems that the answer is **zero**, and numerical calculation verifies the result. But **how can I prove it**?

Intuitively, as $n$ becomes larger and larger, the function $f(x) = \cos{(\frac{n^2}{\cos^2 x})}$ oscillates faster and faster in a bounded region $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, so the integral has to be zero. But why?

Comment: Hence, the limit of the integral does not exist.

Comment: Should be useful to trig substitute $ u = \tan^2 x$ and get $ \int_0^1 \cos[n^2 (u+1)] / [(u+1)\sqrt{u}]du$

Comment: @eyeballfrog I've tried this trick. But I haven't got an answer.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?  As long as eyeballfrog's integral is equivalent, that's all you need to conclude.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That's right. I just thought of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. And I realized that the limit is just a direct corollary of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u= \sec^2x$. Then $dx = du/[u\sqrt{u-1}]$ and we have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos\left[\frac{n^2}{\cos^2 x}\right]dx =\int_1^2\frac{\cos(n^2 u)}{u\sqrt{u-1}}du
$$
Now that the argument of $\cos$ is linear, we can use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which states that for any integrable function $f$,
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos(k x)dx = 0.
$$
The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is the mathematical formulation of your intuition that because the integrand oscillates faster and faster, the integral should go to zero from the cancellation of positive and negative terms.

To apply this to our integral, we choose the function $f$ such that $f(u) = 1/[u\sqrt{u-1}]$ when $u\in (1,2)$ and $f(u) = 0$ elsewhere. This function is clearly integrable, so we have
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos(k x)dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^2 \frac{\cos(k u)}{u\sqrt{u-1}}du = 0.
$$
And it immediately follows that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos\left[\frac{n^2}{\cos^2 x}\right]dx =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_1^2\frac{\cos(n^2 u)}{u\sqrt{u-1}}du = 0.
$$

Comment: Alternatively just use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma stated in terms of the trigonometric functions to begin with. The version in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606446/prove-the-riemann-lebesgue-lemma-intb-afx-cosnxdx-rightarrow-0-as-n-ri) question is sufficient for example

Comment: @Lorago I considered that, but splitting $\cos(n^2 (u+1)$ into $\cos(n^2)\cos(n^2 u) -\sin(n^2)\sin(n^2 u)$ was messy in a way that seemed to detract from the proof.

Comment: Shouldn't substituting $\xi=u+1$ just do the trick?

Comment: @Lorago Oh, right. I had wanted to start the integral at 0 because I thought I might want to scale away the $n^2$ at some point, but I suppose that isn't needed. I'll clean this up a bit then.